# DASL query with variable in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to use a variable in a DASL query but I can't find a way to get the correct syntax.

I couldn't understand what I found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb147588(v%3doffice.12)

**Code**

```
Const PropTag As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/protag/"
' string for DASL Query
strRestriction = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & PropTag _
    & "0x0037001E" & Chr(34) & " like [appointmentToFind]"
```

My variable is `appointmentToFind` and it is a string. I tried `'%[appointmentToFind]%'`, `%[appointmentToFind]%` and `'[appointmentToFind]'` but Visual Basic always reads it as a string and not a variable.

Does someone know which syntax to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it

`like '%" & appointmentToFind & "%'"`